# Replacing/Updating/Modify Cell Value if another cell from same column contain X

Tags: excel, vba, replace, updatepanel, clearcase

**Excel Background**
I got 2 excel column and long records of rows. (example only, as I have more than 10 column)

Column A - It is Either "Yes or No"
Column B - Is a remark. Can type anything I need

**How it works**
This is an ordering system, if date is delayed, Column A will show "Yes"
If no Delay, it will show "No"

**I need**
I need the VBA code to perform the following:

If column B2 contains text "No Delay", Column A2 will change from "Yes" to "No"

**What I have tested**

```
    Private Sub UpdateColumnA()
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 4 To 65536
    Dim InStr As String

    If InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("$M$" & x), "No Delay") Then
        Sheet1.Range("$K$" & x) = Sheet1.Range("$K$" & x) & "No"
        End If

    Next
    End Sub
```

Problem I met above is that, Column A2 "Yes" will become "**YesNo**". I require to replace the Yes to No instead of adding to the existing text.

And if B2 text "**No Delay**" does not match exactly, it will not work at all, hence I want it to be **non case sensitive**, such as "nO Delay" "No DeLAy" will also work.

Answer (score 2):

The option vbTextCompare could make the comparison non case sensitive:

```
InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("$M$" & x), "No Delay", vbTextCompare)
```

And a simple assignation would avoid the concatenation of values ("`YesNo`") in the cell:

```
Sheet1.Range("$K$" & x).Value = "No"
```

Comment: Now instead changing to "No". It change to "false".

Comment: @user try = "" & "No", in order to force a *string* value.

Comment: is there any other method or other vba code able to make this work?

Thanks for the continuous help too :)

Comment: @user1935007 Try `Sheet1.Range("$K$" & x).Value = "No"`, or `Sheet1.Range("$K$" & x).Text = "No"`

Comment: Sheet1.Range("$M$" & x) = Sheet1.Range("$M$" & x).Value = "N"  or Sheet1.Range("$M$" & x) = Sheet1.Range("$M$" & x).text = "N"  doesn't work at all. Still getting the word "False" or "True" instead of Y or N

Comment: @user no, I meant only one =: xxx.Value = "N", not xxx = xxx.Value = "N"

Comment: @user But if it is *still* not working, check the *format* of the cell you want to write into: That format might be set to boolean, and trigger the display False when the value is No (or anything besides 0, for that matter)

Comment: thanks. one =: xxx.Value = "N" , solved my issue. 
You are great :)

Comment: @user1935007 Excellent, I have edited the answer for making the right syntax more visible.